# How can I just get the last record in the java.util.List using subList() or any other method?

Tags: java

Say I have a list of elements whose size is 100. Now I only want the 100th record in the list and the rest of all records from 1-99 should be removed from the list.

I have tried the below piece of code but no change in list size as I see it.
//Output list.size() returns 100

```
list.subList(list.size()-1, list.size());
```

//Output list.size() returns 100 after subList() called...
How can I get just the last record in the java.util.List using subList() or using any other methods available in Java?

Comment: That's because sublist returns a new list.

Comment: Why do you want to return a list with only one index? Are you planning on adding to it? Im just curious as if you only need one index you could return just the item at that index instead of a list

Comment: @Master Yoda, I'm glad to answer your question. 
I'm extracting the data from DB and passing it to list in batches with time interval of 30 seconds. Under each batch of records, I just need the last record to store aside so that I'll start the next batch starting from last record+1 to start the next batch. I know I'm confusing you now but that's all I can explain in short. Thanks for your advise, will use it in future when required.

Comment: @mannedear Ah that makes a lot of sense. Good question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`list.subList` returns a new `List` backed by the original `List`.

You need to store the returned list in a variable in order to use it:

```
List<String> subList = list.subList(list.size()-1, list.size());
```

`subList.size()` will be 1. `list` will remain unchanged.

If you want to remove all but the last element from the original `List`, you can write:

```
list.subList(0, list.size()-1).clear();
```

Now the original `List` will contain just 1 element.

Answer (score 4):

*ArrayList.subList* method returns a sublist of your list without modifying your existing list.

So you need to do;

```
list = list.subList(list.size()-1, list.size());
```

Answer (score 3):

To get just last record without changing list you could use:

```
element = list.get(list.size()-1);
```

this will work for any list, most effective for `ArrayList` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by importing com.google.common.collect.Iterables, but be aware if list is empty it will throw **NoSuchElementException**.

```
public MODEL getLastEntry(List<MODEL> list) {
   return Iterables.getLast(list);
}
```

You can also use stream for it: https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-last-element

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

> How can I get just the last record

In Java 21+…

```
strings.getLast()
```

### `SequencedCollection`

As of Java 21, [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) is a sub-interface of [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html). For details, see [Java JEP 431](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

So now `List` offers a convenient [`getLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#getLast()) method.

```
List< String > strings = List.of( "Alice" , "Bob" , "Carol" ) ;
```

… or the more general `SequencedCollection` rather than `List`:

```
SequencedCollection< String > strings = List.of( "Alice" , "Bob" , "Carol" ) ;
```

Combine that with [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E)) to get a new list made of only the last item.

```
List< String > listOfTheLast = List.of( strings.getLast() ) ;
```